# WSDL is missing while deploying

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wsdl, deployment

i am using vs 2010.

a wsdl is available when starting a webservice in debug mode or release mode at localhost.

a wsdl is missing after publishing the service (via vs, file system and then copy it into a subfolder in wwwroot)

any suggestions so far?

Comment: please close this post. published again and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the .wsdl file - any client can query SWDL via http://PathToYourServiceAsmx?WSDL